# How tightly can I control the Application Pool Recycle Interval in Microsoft IIS?

Tags: iis

I know I can change the default 1740 minutes (29 hour) interval. I know I can set a specific time for the application pool to recycle. I know, I can set user count and memory limits. But what is unclear to me is if I can set it to a specific time interval to start at a certain time. For example, I could set the interval to 10,080 minutes (seven days) but can I also ensure that this interval starts/cycles at 1am Sunday morning?

Comment: Can you provide the code sample you are using?

Comment: It depends on how much accuracy you need, as your Windows time sync might introduce delays, and there are also leap seconds in rare cases to interrupt. You probably cannot always get 1AM sharp.